# undefined symbols for architecture i386:Apple Mach-O Linke(id)error

Tags: ipad, linker-errors

I have an error like this

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can you solve this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 18):

Find the file `ViewController.m` in your project and select it.

Use the properties inspector (Apple-Option-1) to ensure that it's added to your target membership whatever that target may be. It will need have a tick next to the target.

Comment: thats exactly how i solved it on my machine. came after i restarted a new target and added files to it by dragging. Had to do the same for the frameworks

Comment: I had the error and had to uncheck and then re-check the target membership- and then it was fixed.